# How to know if contact is exists uniquely in ContentProvider Uri table

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

How can i check if a specific contact is exist in the android database to add it to the database or not, the problem if i check with contact name there maybe another contact with the same name so can any one help me, my code is :

```
String where = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" = ? ";
String[] whereArg = new String[] {displayName};

Cursor sameName = cResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereArg,null);

if (sameName == null || sameName.getCount() == 0) {
                    // TODO //the addContact method
                }else {

                    // do nothing, the contact is exsist

                }
```